# RadLoopingList with x:bind

Tags: c#, telerik, uwp, uwp-xaml, xaml-binding

I'm using the RadLoopingList from the `Telerik.UI.for.UniversalWindowsPlattform` package. I was wondering, if this control can be used with x:bind inside the ItemTemplate?

I have set the ItemsSource to an `ObservableCollection<MyModel>` like this:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Files, Mode=OneWay}"
```

The problem I'm facing is, that all bindings are being wrapped into an "Item" by the control, so bindings look like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.DisplayName}" />
```

So when I set the `DataContext="MyModel"` and `<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DisplayName}" />` is get this error on running the app

> 'Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::MyAppProject.Models.MyModel was expected.'

Is there a workaround for this issue?

**Update:** here's my full DataTemplate:

```
<telerikLoopingList:RadLoopingList.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="MyModel">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind Item.ThumbnailImage}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Item.File.DisplayName}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerikLoopingList:RadLoopingList.ItemTemplate>



public class MyModel { 

    public string DisplayName;
    public File File;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, you cannot use `x:Bind` in this scenario, here's why:

In the case of the `RadLoopingList`, the bound item is of type `LoopingListDataItem` and the **Item** property is of type `object`. [Go here to see the source code for the LoopingListDataItem](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/master/Controls/Primitives/Primitives.UWP/LoopingList/LoopingListDataItem.cs).

Unfortunately, you cannot set the DataTemplate's `x:DataType` attribute to LoopingListDataItem because it is an **internal** class.

[I have submitted this issue to the UI for UWP repo](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/issues/54) suggesting they change it to a public class so that you can use x:Bind on the ItemTemplate. However, I still foresee other problems as Item property is of type object, but you'll at least be able to use a converter.

**Workaround**

For now, I recommend a hybrid approach: Use x:Bind for the ItemsSource and traditional Binding in the ItemTemplate.

**Example:**

Here's the complete demo I used during my investigation:

MainPage:

```
<Page
x:Class="LoopingListTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:LoopingListTest"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:loopingList="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.LoopingList"
xmlns:viewModels="using:LoopingListTest.ViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <loopingList:RadLoopingList x:Name="LoopingList" 
                                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Files}" >
        <loopingList:RadLoopingList.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Item.ThumbnailImage}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.File.DisplayName}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </loopingList:RadLoopingList.ItemTemplate>
    </loopingList:RadLoopingList>
</Grid>
```

Models:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Files = GenerateFiles();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> GenerateFiles()
    {
        var items = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            items.Add(new MyModel
            {
                ThumbnailImage = "ms-appx:///Images/WindowsLogo.png",
                File = new File
                {
                    DisplayName = $"File {i}"
                }
            });
        }

        return items;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> Files { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public string ThumbnailImage { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is the problem. MyModel has no Item Property, this is being added by the Telerik Control, so the x:DataType will not match the x:Bind since you have to prepend "Item." to each property.

Comment: Thanks for creating this issue. I'd really like to use x:Bind so I can call methods instead of going the DelegateCommand-Way. But that works for now I guess...